# jquery submit model containing multiple objects

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

--I've deleted the original text to try to clean the post up a bit--

--------EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is some more info not sure if it helps anyone that's ran into this issue before.
Here is what my final object looks like in the JS script:

```
var DealerModel = {
    Dealer: {
        AccountId: 5678,
        Name: "Austin",
        City: "Who knows",
        State: "TN"
    },
    Test: 111,
    DealerCategories: [{Name: "Test1", Value:"Value1"},{Name:"Test2", Value:"Value2"}]
}
```

When I pass this into my controller via jquery it has the 111 value for Test, it shows that DealerCategories has 2 objects, but for both those objects as well as Dealer it shows NULL.

I've changed up the model/controller a few times and it seems no matter what if I pass in an object that has a sub json object it doesn't like that. I have a feeling this is something simple i'm missing.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure what the default serialization is for mvc, but you could try adding some [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes.

Comment: The weird thing is lets say I put 2 object into the dealercontacts field in the controller it sees there's suppose to be 2 objects but both objects have all null values. I also do have attributes assigned in the classes I just didnt list them all out in the code section to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

the model binder knows how to bind arrays from JSON so you just have to give him something like this :

```
var DealerModel = 
{
  Dealer : 'my_dealer_value_here',
  DealerContact = [] <- a list of Contrats here
}
```

and i think this should do it.

Comment: I'll try that real quick but it seemed to be giving me issues when trying that. the "Dealer" segment needs to submit id, account number, name ect but when I was trying that before it kept just passing null values for everything. I would debug out the json before submitting it and it was certainly passing them. Be right back though!

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is with taking the leap from posting simple values like strings and numbers through jQuery.post, you can also provide json objects, like the one listed by Alex, above.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'MYURL',
  data: {
     Dealer : {id:-1, accountId: '', name:'TheDealer'},
     DealerContact: [{FirstName:'ContactName',...},{...},...]
  }
});
```

And that bit of data should deserialize to your objects.

Comment: Thats not the problem(at least I hope not ;) )

Comment: Ait. Was simply trying to guess where it's going wrong. I'll ask some questions upstairs.